# Calculate the 3rd point of an equilateral triangle from two points at any angle, pointing the "correct" way for a Koch Snowflake

Tags: math, geometry, labview, fractals

Perhaps the question title needs some work.

For context this is for the purpose of a Koch Snowflake (using C-like math syntax in a formula node in LabVIEW), thus why the triangle must be the correct way. (As given 2 points an equilateral triangle may be in one of two directions.)

To briefly go over the algorithm: I have an array of 4 predefined coordinates initially forming a triangle, the first "generation" of the fractal. To generate the next iteration, one must for each line (pair of coordinates) get the 1/3rd and 2/3rd midpoints to be the base of a new triangle on that face, and then **calculate the position of the 3rd point of the new triangle** (the subject of this question). Do this for all current sides, concatenating the resulting arrays into a new array that forms the next generation of the snowflake.

The array of coordinates is in a clockwise order, e.g. each vertex travelling clockwise around the shape corresponds to the next item in the array, something like this for the 2nd generation:

[image: index vs vertices]

This means that when going to add a triangle to a face, e.g. between, in that image, the vertices labelled 0 and 1, you first get the midpoints which I'll call "c" and "d", you can just rotate "d" *anti*-clockwise around "c" by 60 degrees to find where the new triangle top point will be (labelled `e`).

[image: new triangle]

I believe this should hold (e.g. 60 degrees anticlockwise rotating the later point around the earlier) for *anywhere* around the snowflake, however currently my maths only seems to work in the case where the initial triangle has a vertical side: [(0,0), (0,1)]. Else wise the triangle goes off in some other direction.

I believe I have correctly constructed my loops such that the triangle generating VI (virtual instrument, effectively a "function" in written languages) will work on each line segment sequentially, but my actual calculation isn't working and I am at a loss as to how to get it in the right direction. Below is my current maths for calculating the triangle points from a single line segment, where `a` and `b` are the original vertices of the segment, `c` and `d` form new triangle base that are in-line with the original line, and `e` is the part that sticks out. I don't want to call it "top" as for a triangle formed from a segment going from upper-right to lower-left, the "top" will stick down.

```
cx = ax + (bx - ax)/3;
dx = ax + 2*(bx - ax)/3;


cy = ay + (by - ay)/3;
dy = ay + 2*(by - ay)/3;



dX = dx - cx;
dY = dy - cy;



ex = (cos(1.0471975512) * dX + sin(1.0471975512) * dY) + cx;
ey = (sin(1.0471975512) * dX + cos(1.0471975512) * dY) + cy;
```

note `1.0471975512` is just 60 degrees in radians.

Currently for generation 2 it makes this: (note the seemingly separated triangle to the left is formed by the 2 triangles on the top and bottom having their `e` vertices meet in the middle and is not actually an independent triangle.)

[image: horribly broken]

I suspect the necessity for having slightly different equations depending on weather `ax` or `bx` is larger etc, perhaps something to do with how the periodicity of sin/cos may need to be accounted for (something about quadrants in spherical coordinates?), as it looks like the misplaced triangles are at 60 degrees, just that the angle is between the wrong lines. However this is a guess and I'm just not able to imagine how to do this programmatically let alone on paper.

Thankfully the maths formula node allows for if and else statements which would allow for this to be implemented *if* it's the case but as said I am not awfully familiar with adjusting for what I'll naively call the "quadrants thing", and am unsure how to know which quadrant one is in for each case.

This was a long and rambling question which inevitably tempts nonsense so if you've any clarifying questions please comment and I'll try to fix anything/everything.

Comment: One of the `sin(1.0471975512)` needs a minus sign

Comment: You're absolutely right and I am a fool!! I fiddled back and forth with tiny changes I must've skipped over it. So close for so long... As a bonus I changed the wrong one at first and produced an anti-koch so enjoy this rather pretty creation! https://i.imgur.com/0xzFcY1.png

Comment: You should keep that version as an option ...

Comment: Yes, I'll put in a switch case for it. Personally think its far more aesthetically pleasing! Unfortunately this is being written to a spec that doesn't ask for it so I've my doubts on whether it should be included though. I suppose if I code it in to just not run unless a hardcoded switch is changed then all is well?

Comment: You also could try out doing one or two levels with the normal formula, and the following levels with the anti-clockwise version. Anyway, it all depends on the direction of the initial triangle. Instead of asking for number of levels, you could ask two numbers: one for the number of normal levels and one for the number of "anti" levels? When nothing entered, defaulting to zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering my own question thanks to @JohanC, Unsurprisingly this was a case of making many tiny adjustments and giving up just before getting it right.

The correct formula was this:

```
ex = (cos(1.0471975512) * dX + sin(1.0471975512) * dY) + cx;
ey = (-sin(1.0471975512) * dX + cos(1.0471975512) * dY) + cy;
```

just adding a minus to the second sine function. Note that if one were travelling anticlockwise then one would want to rotate points clockwise, so you instead have the 1st sine function negated and the second one positive.

[image]